# TensorFlow で表示された FutureWarning にはどう対応すればよい？

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow

PythonでTensorFlowを実装していると画像にあるFutureWarningが出てしまいました.どうしたらいいのでしょうか?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

放置する
  出ているのはエラーではなく、「将来的には問題が起こります」というお知らせ(Warning) ですから、とりあえず無視してもかまいません。非推奨になっているだけで、動作しない訳ではありませんから。
　そのうち、Tensolflowの新しいバージョンが提供されて、問題は解決するだろうと思います。

pandasをupgradeすることで解決したとの記事がありました。
[TensorFlowをPython 3.6.4で入れてSyntaxErrorになった。](http://yondakana.blogspot.com/2018/02/tensorflowpython-364syntaxerror.html)

Warningが出るのが気になるなら、試してみてはどうでしょう。